# Node REST API Image rendering issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, gridfs

I have an issue to display a simple image on a web page. I have a node backend for the APIs and a node web server for the view pages.
The code was working very well but I need to add a sort of gateway in-between (that will handle authentication in the future) and it broke the code.

I am using express and gridfs to store and retrive from mongo the files.

Here is the code

**HTML/Angular page**

```html
<img id="image" ng-src="http:localhost:3000/api/files/images/{{data.image}}" alt="" />
```

**Gateway (node)**

```js
var request = require('request');

//settings - retrive the url of the api backend micro-service
var url = require('./configApiGw').url_service_api_contents; 

//api to retrive a file stored in mongo using gridfs
app.get('/api/files/images/:id', function(req, res, next){
    var uri = url+'/api/files/images/:'+req.params.id;
    request({
        uri: uri,
        method: "GET",
        timeout: 100000,
        followRedirect: true,
        maxRedirects: 10
    }, function(error, response, body) {    
            res.send(response.body);
    }); 
});
```

**Backend API**

```js
app.get('/api/files/images/:id', function(req, res, next){
    //call function to read the file using gridfs. call back function
    readFile(req, res, function(file){
        console.log('success');
    });
});

function readFile(req,res,callback){
  var fileId = req.params.id;

  //delete the ':' that is added by the gateway
  if(fileId.charAt(0) === ':'){
    fileId = fileId.slice(1);
  }

  // streaming from gridfs
  var rstream = gfs.createReadStream({filename: fileId});
  var bufs = [];

  rstream.on('data', function (chunk) {
    bufs.push(chunk);
  });

  // done reading the file 
  rstream.on('end', function () { 
    var fbuf = Buffer.concat(bufs);
    var file = (fbuf.toString('base64'));
    callback(file);
  });

  //error handling, e.g. file does not exist
  rstream.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log('An error occurred!', err);
    console.log(err);
    res.send(500,err);
  }); 

  rstream.pipe(res);
}
```

The image does not display but I get a 200 OK response from both API backend and gateway.
When I look at the image details on the browser, I see the following data:
- Location: http://localhost:3000/api/files/images/file.jpeg
- Type: text/html
- Size: Unknown (not cached)

What am I doing wrong? thanks a lot.

**Edit with Alexandr inputs**

**Gateway (Node) V2**

```js
var request = require('request');

//settings - retrive the url of the api backend micro-service
var url = require('./configApiGw').url_service_api_contents; 

app.get('/api/files/images/:id', function(req, res, next){
var uri = url+'/api/files/images/:'+req.params.id;
request({
    uri: uri,
    method: "GET",
    timeout: 100000,
    followRedirect: true,
    maxRedirects: 10
}, function(error, response, body) { 
        res.set('Content-Type', response.headers['content-type']);   
        res.send(response.body);
   }); 
});
```

**Backend API V2**

```js
//api to retrive a file stored in mongo using gridfs
app.get('/api/files/images/:id', function(req, res, next){
    //call function to read the file using gridfs. call back function
    db.readFile(req, res, function(file){
      //res.send(file);
      console.log("success");
  });
});

readFile = function(req,res,callback){
  var fileId = req.params.id;

  //delete the ':' that is added by the gateway
  if(fileId.charAt(0) === ':'){
    fileId = fileId.slice(1);
  }

  //setHeaders content type for the file
  setHeaders(fileId, function(contentType){
    res.writeHead('200',{'Content-Type':contentType});

    // streaming from gridfs
    var rstream = gfs.createReadStream({filename: fileId});
    var bufs = [];

    rstream.on('data', function (chunk) {
      bufs.push(chunk);
    });

    // done reading the file 
    rstream.on('end', function () { 
      var fbuf = Buffer.concat(bufs);
      var file = (fbuf.toString('binary'));

      callback(file);
    });

    //error handling, e.g. file does not exist
    rstream.on('error', function (err) {
      console.log('An error occurred!', err);
     console.log(err);
      res.send(500,err);
    }); 

    rstream.pipe(res);

  });
};

function setHeaders(fileId, callback){
  var ext = path.extname(fileId);
  var contentType = 'text/html';
    if (ext === '.gif') {
       contentType = 'image/gif';
    }
    if (ext === '.jpeg') {
       contentType = 'image/jepg';
    }
    if (ext === '.png') {
       contentType = 'image/png';
    }
    if (ext === '.jpg') {
       contentType = 'image/jpg';
    }
  callback(contentType);
}
```

The result is still not good: the image is not displayed. BUT now, the content-type is correctly set.

adding here the headers (postman):

```js
Access-Control-Allow-Headers → Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept
Access-Control-Allow-Origin → *
Connection → keep-alive
Content-Length → 82360
Content-Type → image/jepg; charset=utf-8
Date → Fri, 20 Nov 2015 10:15:55 GMT
ETag → W/"141b8-Ox5qDdvc3kZTunf0uqMVQg"
X-Powered-By → Express
```

Comment: Just a question about the gate way. As you are using AngularJs why can't you create a controller.js file? and use that as a gateway. Basically create a angularJS controller and create a very basic Javascript HTTP call to retrieve your data. That HTTP call would go to the route in your Node API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Try to set `encoding` property to `null` in the request object:

```
app.get('/api/files/images/:id', function(req, res, next){
var uri = url+'/api/files/images/:'+req.params.id;
request({
    uri: uri,
    method: "GET",
    timeout: 100000,
    followRedirect: true,
    encoding: null, 
    maxRedirects: 10
}, function(error, response, body) { 
        res.set('Content-Type', response.headers['content-type']);   
        res.send(response.body);
   }); 
});
```

Also, set image content-type headers to your responses:

```
app.get('/api/files/images/:id', function(req, res, next){
    //call function to read the file using gridfs. call back function
    readFile(req, res, function(file){
        res.set('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg'); //it can different, depends on the image
        res.send(file);
    });
});
```

Gateway:

```
app.get('/api/files/images/:id', function(req, res, next){
var uri = url+'/api/files/images/:'+req.params.id;
request({
    uri: uri,
    method: "GET",
    timeout: 100000,
    followRedirect: true,
    maxRedirects: 10
}, function(error, response, body) { 
        res.set('Content-Type', response.headers['content-type']);   
        res.send(response.body);
   }); 
});
```

Comment: If I set the headers exactly as in your example, I get a error saying that i cannot set the headers once the response already sent. So I have moved the res.set content type before streaming the file from DB. It is better because now I have the right content type. But I still don't have anything displayed on the page. If I add the res.send(file) in the readFile callback, I get an error "can't send headers after they are sent". So I wonder if my issue is not related to my callback function.

Comment: And what was the result?

Comment: interesting to note that it is working with HTML file: I get the file correctly displayed. But does not work for image. I don't understand why. Maybe the encoding?

Comment: Can you print please request headers?

Comment: By the way,  you should use  `data-ng-src` instead of `ng-src`.

Comment: this is the headers (using postman) 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers → Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept
Access-Control-Allow-Origin → *
Connection → keep-alive
Content-Length → 82360
Content-Type → image/jepg; charset=utf-8
Date → Fri, 20 Nov 2015 10:15:55 GMT
ETag → W/"141b8-Ox5qDdvc3kZTunf0uqMVQg"
X-Powered-By → Express'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95672/discussion-between-lazarev-alexandr-and-edevregille).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I am already using a controller for all the other components of the page but I call directly from the html page the API to retrive the image. You're right, I could change that.
The gateway is here also because I have multiple API components (micro-service architecture) and so the gateway is a great way to abstract all these different components for the web client.
I would prefer to keep the gateway to follow the microservices architecture pattern.